# Seg fault for writing to CR0

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm trying to write to CR0 in Linux, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. This for assembly of i386 or x86_64. Is there anyway of getting around this?

Bellow is part of the code that sets the segfault.

```
mov eax,0xffffffff      ;system call number (sys_write)
mov cr0,eax
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? From the comment, it seems you are trying to perform a system call but `0xffffffff` is definitely not the number for `sys_write`.

Comment: I wrote to eax 0xfffffff because you can't do mem to mem operations. You need at least one register. Even though cr0 is a register, I only used eax as a means of being safe. Basically I want to turn off protection mode from user space. However from I have recently learned, cpu's these days are fairly advanced and places code in protected segments that doesn't allow it to mess with certain registers if that segment does not have that privilege 0.

Comment: Setting CR0 to all-ones would disable cache, disable the x87 FPU, and do other weird stuff.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#CR0.  If you were actually in kernel mode like the original tags on this question indicated, it wouldn't fault directly, but user-space probably would soon after.

Answer (score 7):

CR0 is a protected register.  It cannot be modified in a userspace linux application.